# Matrix Market files and Stata

Tags: stata, sparse-matrix

I want to read a [Matrix Market exchange file](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/formats.html) into Stata. For example, I've got a sparse matrix `auth.mfx` created by the Python command `sio.mmwrite()` which I would like to have as a spatial weights matrix. The respective command `spatwmat` requires a `.dta` file:

```
insheet using "auth_matrix.mtx", clear
```

just reads the file as a text file, but not as a matrix. Is there a way to read matrix market files into Stata? Obviously, they are a recognized format in R, Python, Matlab, Fortran, etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, Stata has no specific command for *Matrix Market files* (none that I know of). But I guess you could try to do this indirectly.

Stata imports data with the presumption that it is a Stata dataset (see `help import`), i.e. variables layed out as columns, each row being one observation.

You can read the *Matrix Market file* with, e.g. Python, output to some form that Stata can understand (again `help import`) and then check `help mkmat`, to convert the dataset to a Stata matrix.

See also `help mata`, the preferred way of doing advanced matrix operations within Stata.

The alternative is to write your own command that parses the *Matrix Market file*, which is after all, an ASCII file. See `help program`, if interested.